# How can I use `glab api` commands to configure settings that don't have a developed UI?

Tags: gitlab, glab

According to the [documentation on Merge Request Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#prerequisites),

> To prevent users from running new pipelines for fork projects in the parent project use [the projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project) to disable the `ci_allow_fork_pipelines_to_run_in_parent_project` setting.
>
> > Pipelines created before the setting was disabled are not affected and continue to run. If you rerun a job in an older pipeline, the job uses the same context as when the pipeline was originally created.

How can I do that with glab? There is no example of setting REST parameters `glab api --help`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right syntax to set this attribute for a project `evancarroll/foo` is,

```sh
glab api "projects/evancarroll%2ffoo" \
  -X PUT \
  -f "ci_allow_fork_pipelines_to_run_in_parent_project=false"
```

Note the project here is `evancarroll/foo` but you must url encode the `/` with `%2f`.